# Need to get array values

Tags: magento2.2.6, array

```
 Array
(
    [requestId] => 69a6#16a49c12847
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [seq] => 0
                    [marketoGUID] => d6a515c3-b1d4-4b68-bc61-6d40bf0387a5
                    [status] => created
                )

        )

    [success] => 1
)
```

I need to get status value from this array. I am getting like this $responseDecode['result'][0]['status']. But it's not working

Comment: what is the error you facing?

Comment: Does it is json responce? And which version of magento?

Comment: Yes, It is json response $responseDecode = json_decode(($response), true); and magento2 version is 2.2.6

Comment: With this code I am getting error in console
 VM10057:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
 */
protected $jsonHelper;

/**
 * [__construct description]
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data              $jsonHelper        [description]
 */
public function __construct(
    .......
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    .......
) {
    .......
    $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    .......
}

public function yourFunction() {
    $strToArr = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($response);
    echo $strToArr['result']['0']['status'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to wrap the **`$response`** with parenthesis

```
$responseDecode = json_decode($response, true);
```

And you can get the status the same way you did:

```
$responseDecode['result']['0']['status']
```

Note: **`0`** should be inside single quote

Comment: I tried also like this $responseDecode = json_decode($response, true);

Comment: yeah but you should take note that **`0`** should be inside single quote also otherwise it will return an undefined offset

Comment: @Shiwani did you try it? did it work or you get any errors?

Comment: $responseDecode['result']['0']['status']  Code is not working

Comment: try `echo $responseDecode['result']['0']['status'];` and check what you get. It should work as per info given above

Comment: Okay, Let me do again

Comment: okay no problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decode your json data and then you can print value.

$array = json_decode($responseDecode);
echo $array['result'][0]['status'];